# Pingbacks and Trackbacks in Timber

Tags: timber

Does Timber supports Pingbacks And Trackbacks? Did not find in the documentation.

Need something like that:

```
{% for ping in post.pings %}
  {% include 'partials/pingback.twig' with { ping: ping } %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

**single.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying Singe Post.
 */
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = Timber::query_post();

$type = $post->post_type;
$protected = post_password_required($post->ID);

$context['post'] = $post;
$context['post']->pings = get_comments([
  'post_id' => $post->ID,
  'type' => 'pings',
  'order' => 'ASC'
]);

if ($protected) {
  Timber::render('single-password.twig', $context);
} else {
  Timber::render([
    'single-' . $post->ID . '.twig',
    'single-' . $type . '.twig',
    'single.twig',
  ], $context);
}
```

**single.twig**

```html
{% if post.pings %}
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="heading-1 mb-2">
      {{ post.pings|length }} {{ __('Pingbacks and Trackbacks', textdomain) }}
    </h3>

    <div class="pingbacks">
      {% for ping in post.pings %}
        <div class="pingbacks__item">
          {{ __('Pingback:', textdomain) }} <a href="{{ ping.comment_author_url }}" targer="_blank">{{ ping.comment_author }}</a>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: And `ping.comment_content` for the text of the pingback.